# How can I close the solution explorer panel with a key-board shortcut in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I often need to jump from a file to another file that I don't have open to one somewhere in the project directory structure.  I often use Ctrl-Alt-L to open the solution explorer panel, but then I'd like to close it after I open the file I'm after.  Unfortunately Ctrl-Alt-L doesn't simply toggle the panel open/closed.  Is there another way to accomplish this.  Or how can I close the solution explorer panel with a key-board shortcut?

Comment: I would have accepted both answers below even though they 'technically' aren't 100% what I was: explicitly a short-cut for 'close the solution explorer'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn on the Auto-Hide option for the Solution Explorer panel. Now you can open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and close it with <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Actually Esc will set the focus back to the code editor and the Solution Explorer will auto-hide itself.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you are looking for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESCAPE</kbd>.

It will close any tool window currently in focus.

Answer (score 2):

It takes two steps:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to put the Solution Explorer into focus.
2. Then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close the tool window currently in focus.

Thank you Smash for the second step.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `Auto-Hide` in the Solution Explorer panel, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and release only the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, that will open this dialog with **Active Tools** and **Active Files** lists. Select your prefered item using the keyboard or mouse.

[image]